# How to write one better sql of below two statements to improve the performance

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

If more than one ID for a match select id with max(date) .
if more than one id for above max dates select max(ID)
Go to TABLE1 to get high-dated IDS

Step 1 : identifying IDs which are having max dates

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TEST_VT 
AS 
(                                       
SELECT
TABLE1.ID ,
TABLE1.KEY1,
TABLE1.STRT_DT,
TABLE1.TERM_DT,
Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY  TABLE1.KEY1 ORDER BY TABLE1.STRT_DT DESC , TABLE1.ID DESC) RNK
FROM TABLE2          
INNER JOIN TABLE1         
ON TABLE2.KEY1=TABLE1.KEY1    
WHERE  TABLE1.TERM_DT='8888-12-31'
QUALIFY RNK=1
GROUP BY 
1,2,3,4
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(ID,KEY1) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Go to TABLE1 to get high-dated KEY1S associated with IDS from ABOVE STEP
Step 2 : If there is more than one max date take max ID out of all matched records in above step

```
SELECT                                      
TABLE1.ID ,
TABLE1.KEY1,
TABLE1.STRT_DT,
TABLE1.TERM_DT,                             
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE1.KEY1 ORDER BY TABLE1.STRT_DT DESC , TABLE1.ID DESC) AS RNK                 
FROM  TABLE1    
INNER JOIN TEST_VT                                      
ON TEST_VT.ID=TABLE1.ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3                   
ON TABLE3.KEY1=TABLE1.KEY1    
WHERE  TABLE1.TERM_DT='8888-12-31'  
QUALIFY RNK=1 
GROUP BY    
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: CAn you share some sample data and desired results. It's very difficult to backwards engineer your sql to understand the underlying data and what you are trying to do to manipulate it.

Comment: Let me work on it thanks.

Comment: It appears Table2 and Table3 are only used to filter the results? What is the purpose of the GROUP BY? If you are just trying to make RANK unique, use ROW_NUMBER instead.